# How to convert CryptoPP::Integer to char*

Tags: c++, visual-c++, crypto++

I want to convert myVar from `CryptoPP:Integer` to `char*` or to String :
The code is below :

```
CryptoPP::Integer myVar = pubKey.ApplyFunction(m);
std::cout << "result: " << std::hex << myVar<< std::endl;
```

I have been searching the Internet for converting `CryptoPP:Integer` to `char*` but I have had no luck finding. So, either it is really a problem with all to convert `CryptoPP:Integer` to `char*`, either I didn't understand very well type `CryptoPP:Integer` within C++ .

Can someone help me please?

Comment: `char*` is C and not C++ will purists say. Do you really want to fiddle with `char*` and array of `char`? Try `snprintf`.

Comment: @harper: Suggesting *printf() is reasonable, but the unsafe-by-design `sprintf()` should be avoided in favor of `snprintf()`.

Comment: There is nothing in my code that allow us to say "the integer holds a memory adress". If you want I will publish all the code !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way, without knowing much more about `CryptoPP::Integer` other than it clearly supports `<<` as implied by your question, is to use `std::stringstream`:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex /*if required*/ << myVar;
```

Extract the underlying `std::string` using, say `std::string s = ss.str();`. You can then use `s.c_str()` to access the `const char*` buffer for as long as `s` is in scope. Don't change `s` in any way once you've called and relied upon the result of `c_str()` as the behaviour of doing so and subsequently relying on that result is *undefined*.

There are neater C++11 solutions but that requires you (and me) to know more about the type.

Comment: +1 indeed it does support `std::ostream` dumping. [Use The Source, Luke (line 3371)](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/integer_8cpp_source.html).

Comment: "that requires you (and me) to know more about the type" - Google can help with that: http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_integer.html (and confirms that it is streamable, and there doesn't seem to be any "neater" way).

Comment: Assuming, of course, that CryptoPP is one of those things. OP doesn't reveal that to us. Yes, I know I'm bordering on feline pedantry here.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Indeed. The `crypto++` tag lends some weight to that assumption.

Answer (score 5):

With Boost:

```
boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(myVar);
```

C++98:

```
std::ostringstream stream;
stream << myVar;
stream.str();
```

Comment: that should be `strlen(str)-1` instead of `sizeof(str)`; in `C` example

Comment: itoa,ltoa from stdlib?

Comment: Neither `std::to_string` nor `snprintf` will work with arbitrary class types. Streaming (directly or through `lexical_cast`) should work though.

Comment: @Ulterior: No, there's nothing in the C library that can convert a C++ class type to a string.

Comment: @Aniket: what you're proposing would invoke undefined behavior.  sizeof is correct for use with snprintf().

Comment: @n.m.: thanks, I hadn't realized this Integer was a class and not a typedef for some sort of regular integer.  I'll remove the offending parts of my answer and leave the parts that work given this.

Comment: I tested the solution number 1 and I have error :
to_string  is not a member of std !
However I'm using VS2010 pro.
What I know that VS 2010 support C++11 !

Comment: @xtensa1408 - The ***`to_string is not a member of std`*** is likely coming from Boost, and not Crypto++. The library cannot provide an `Integer` specialization of `to_string` because it not a template function. And the library cannot add symbols to the `std` namespace. Also see [Is specialization of std::to_string for custom types allowed by the C++ standard?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36533199/608639)

Answer (score 3):

There's a few different ways you can do this, depending on what you want. `char*` does not provide enough information in this case.

Here's what you get when using the insertion operator:

```
byte buff[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
CryptoPP::Integer n(buff, sizeof(buff));

cout << "Oct: " << std::oct << n << endl;
cout << "Dec: " << std::dec << n << endl;
cout << "Hex: " << std::hex << n << endl;
```

That results in:

```
$ ./cryptopp-test.exe
Oct: 4414533066157o
Dec: 310939249775.
Hex: 48656c6c6fh
```

---

However, if you want to get the original string "hello" (re: your Raw RSA project):

```
byte buff[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
CryptoPP::Integer n(buff, sizeof(buff));

size_t len = n.MinEncodedSize();
string str;

str.resize(len);
n.Encode((byte *)str.data(), str.size(), Integer::UNSIGNED);

cout << "Str: " << str << endl;
```

That results in:

```
$ ./cryptopp-test.exe
Str: Hello
```

---

If, however, you just want the string used in an `Integer`, then:

```
Integer i("11111111111111111111");    
ostringstream oss;

oss << i;    
string str = oss.str();

cout << str << endl;
```

That results in:

```
$ ./cryptopp-test.exe
1111111111111111111.
```

Answer (score 2):

If `CryptoPP::Integer` can be sent to output streams like `std::cout` (as your code seems to suggest), then you can use [**`std::ostringstream`**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/ostringstream/):

```
#include <sstream>  // For std::ostringstream
....

std::string ToString(const CryptoPP::Integer& n)
{
    // Send the CryptoPP::Integer to the output stream string
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << n;    
    // or, if required:
    //     os << std::hex << n;  

    // Convert the stream to std::string
    return os.str();
}
```

Then, once you have a `std::string` instance, you can convert it to `const char*` using **`std::string::c_str()`**.
(But I think in C++ code you should use a *safe* string class like `std::string` in general, instead of raw C-style character pointers).

---

**PS**
I'm assuming `CryptoPP::Integer` is *not* a trivial typedef for an `int`.
If you want to convert an `int` to a `std::string`, then you may want to just use C++11's [**`std::to_string()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).