# Is specialization of std::to_string for custom types allowed by the C++ standard?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, tostring, specialization

In C++11 and later, is it allowed to specialize `std::to_string` in the `std` namespace for custom types?

```
namespace std {
string to_string(::MyClass const & c) { return c.toString(); }
}
```

Sample use-case:

```
int main() {
    MyClass c;
    std::cout << std::to_string(c) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> In C++11 and later, is it allowed to specialize std::to_string in the std namespace for custom types?

No. First of all, [it is not a template function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) so you can't specialize it at all.

If you're asking about adding your own overload functions the answer still remains the same.

Documentation snippet from [Extending the namespace std](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std):

> It is undefined behavior to add declarations or definitions to namespace std or to any namespace nested within std, with a few exceptions noted below
>
> It is allowed to add template specializations for any standard library template to the namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization satisfies all requirements for the original template, except where such specializations are prohibited.

---

In practice everything will probably work just fine but strictly speaking the standard says there is no guarantee of what will happen.

---

Edit: I don't have access to the official standard so the following is from the [free working draft (N4296)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf):

> **17.6.4.2** Namespace use
>
> **17.6.4.2.1** Namespace std
>
> 1. The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a
>      namespace within namespace std unless otherwise specified. A program may add a template specialization
>      for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type
>      and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly
>      prohibited.<sup>181</sup>
> 2. The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it declares
>
>    2.1 — an explicit specialization of any member function of a standard library class template, or
>
>    2.2 — an explicit specialization of any member function template of a standard library class or class template,
>      or
>
>    2.3 — an explicit or partial specialization of any member class template of a standard library class or class
>      template.
>
>    A program may explicitly instantiate a template defined in the standard library only if the declaration
>      depends on the name of a user-defined type and the instantiation meets the standard library requirements
>      for the original template.
> 3. A translation unit shall not declare namespace std to be an inline namespace (7.3.1).

Comment: No guarantee.. Undefined? I can't believe this is undefined behaviour. Specializing for any other namespace works just fine. I highly doubt there would be any consequences in terms of program behaviour. I think the standard should just say that it's prohibited and not call it undefined if it really isn't. How can this cause undefined behaviour?

Comment: @Brandon: We generally expect compilers to error out when we do prohibited things, but requiring compilers to detect and diagnose this sort of thing is unrealistic. Hence, UB.

Comment: This is sad. I wish they'd make an exception for `std::to_string`. Or as an alternative, provide some other means to specialize it, e.g. using something like `template <class T> auto f(T && t) -> std::enable_if_t<ToStringSpec<std::decay_t<T> >::value, void> { ToStringSpec<std::decay_t<T> >()(std::forward<T>(t)); }`

Comment: footnote referenced in 17.6.4.2 quote: *181)
Any library code that instantiates other library templates must be prepared to work adequately with any user-supplied
specialization that meets the minimum requirements of the Standard.*

Comment: What about writing a cast operator `operator std::string` instead as an alternative to `to_string`?

Comment: @jaques-sam this is ugly. There has to be a consistensy for casting things to strings. So when you write a generic template code you don't have to work around cases when there  is `std::to_string` to be used or `static_cast<std::string>`. The former is prettier. This is really a shame that the standar library is so inconsistent. There are cases that provide customization points and cases like `std::to_string`.

Answer (score 19):

If I'm not mistaken you can simply overload `to_string` for a generic type:

```
template<typename T> to_string(const T& _x) {
    return _x.toString();
}
```

and this allows use of ADL (argument dependent lookup) by your program to correctly choose the relevant `to_string` method based upon the type passed.

Comment: Are you suggesting this be done in the `std` namespace or outside of it?

Comment: @JamesAdkison Outside of it

Comment: This would only work for unqualified function calls like `to_string(myObject)`, but not for qualified function calls like `std::to_string(myObject)`.

Comment: @jotik Yes that's true

Comment: @jotik: Well, that's best.  A qualified call to `std::to_string(myObject)` is going out of its way to request the vanilla behavior provided by the Standard.

Comment: @BenVoigt I can see how `std::to_string(myObject)` could occur unintentionally, thanks to templates.  If `myObject` is of a custom numeric type, and is passed to a templated function that operates on numeric types, it's possible that the function would naively try to use `std::to_string(myObject)`, if it assumes that it'll only be passed fundamental arithmetic types.

Comment: @JustinTime> if it does it's improperly written. Correct way is to `using std::to_string; to_string(myObject);` This will do the right thing, whatever the type of `myObject`.

Comment: @spectras +1. I also want this answer to have more votes so it answers the next logical question: "how do you do provide your own to_string then?"

Answer (score 14):

> In C++11 and later, is it allowed to specialize std::to_string in the std namespace for custom types?

No, you can't add an overload into the `std` namespace for `to_string()`.

The good news is that **you don't need to, there is a simple solution!**

You can provide your own implementation and let ADL (argument dependent lookup) solve the problem for you.

Here's how:

```
class A {};

std::string to_string(const A&)
{
    return "A()";
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    using std::to_string;
    std::cout << to_string(2) << ' ' << to_string(a);
}
```

Here we used the [using declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-declarations) to bring `std::to_string` into the scope, and then we used the unqualified call to `to_string()`.

Now both `std::to_string` and `::to_string` are visible and the compiler picks the appropriate overload.

If you don't want to write `using std::to_string` before using `to_string` every time or you fear you will forget to use `to_string` without the namespace you can create an helper function

```
template<typename T>
std::string my_to_string(T&& t)
{
    using std::to_string;
    return to_string(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

Note that this function can be defined in any namespace and works independently of the namespace in which the classes are defined (they don't have to be the same).

See the [example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZhNqZWoX3cLOrAuX).

**NOTE**: this works if you are the one calling `to_string`. If there is a library that calls `std::to_string` and you want to change it for your types you are out of luck.

Comment: I think linker substitution might be able to help if you need to make the library call your function when it calls `std::to_string`. Used in TDD when you depend on a library which you can't edit but still have to mock in your tests. In this case you'd have to forward all calls to the default std library from your substituted one, except for the `std::to_string`, which would call your implementation instead, which would then in turn either call your `to_string` or the actual `std::to_string`.

Answer (score 10):

Better way would be to create your own function that make use of `std::to_string` if it's possible as well as the `.toString()` method whenever it's available for passed argument:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct MyClass {
   std::string toString() const { return "MyClass"; }
};

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<const T&>().toString()), std::string>::value, std::string>::type my_to_string(const T &t) {
    return t.toString();
}

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<decltype(std::to_string(std::declval<T&>())), std::string>::value, std::string>::type my_to_string(const T &t) {
    return std::to_string(t);
}

int main() {
   std::cout << my_to_string(MyClass()) << std::endl; // will invoke .toString
   std::cout << my_to_string(1) << std::endl; //will invoke std::to_string
}
```